# why get_class is needed in ActiveQueryTrait::createModels of Yii2 framework?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I am exploring the source code of [Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2) framework. But I am confused about `line 132` in `ActiveQueryTrait::createModels`, I am going to paste the code here:

```
        $class = $this->modelClass;
        if ($this->indexBy === null) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $model = $class::instantiate($row);
                $modelClass = get_class($model);
                $modelClass::populateRecord($model, $row);
                $models[] = $model;
            }
        }
```

my question was that is it necessary to use `get_class` to get an `ActiveRecord`'s subclass name again? `$this->modelClass` has already be set to an `ActiveRecord`'s subclass name somewhere else.